# How to perform analysis on a potentially malicious .torrent file?

Tags: torrent

I was recently sent a .torrent file from what I had thought was a trusted source, but when I opened it with qBittorrent, the computer automatically rebooted. I had already scanned the file with Kaspersky and Windows Defender, which both showed it was clean. After the reboot, I tried to open it with a different client, Deluge, which told me the file was in some way corrupted and could not be used. Though I know it is said that .torrent files are a really uncommon attack vector, I find it unlikely that this is a coincidence, and so I'd like to perform further testing in a VM. How can I "look under the hood" on the file in a safe environment to determine if it is indeed malicious. I have already disconnected the affected machine, removed the network cord and unplugged it from the wall so that it cannot perform any autonomous actions.

Comment: Torrent files are text files. Open with notepad? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#File_structure

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend uploading a copy of the original file to VirusTotal so that experts can analyze it.

You can look into online resources about how to reverse engineer malware, but there are people that already have those skills and contributing to their community will benefit everyone if new malware is discovered.